# Linear transformation (Ax) and the solution set

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

given that 
$$A \in \mathbb{R}^{mxn} , S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n, b \in \mathbb{R}^m$$

Where all elements (x) in S satisfy the inequality
$$Ax \le b$$
Then S must be a convex set

I was tasked to show that this holds for a special case where $A_{i,j} \ge 0 \forall i,j$. But i don't know why this must hold? i made the following that i believe should  be enough to show that S is a convex set:

S is convex iff $A(px_1+(1-p)x_2) \le b \forall x_1,x_2 \in S$
$$Apx_1 + A(1-p)x_2 \le pb + (1-p)b = b$$

Im unaware what part would be faulty if we generalise?

Comment: What on earth does $Ax \le b$ mean when $m > 1$? Do you mean to have some norms in your inequality?

Comment: I meant that $(Ax)_i \le b_i$ for i = {1,..,m} . Im unaware if that is not the usual meaning?

Comment: $Ax_i$ looks like $A$ times the scalar $x_i$. Do you mean to say that each entry of $Ax$ is less than or equal to the corresponding entry of $b$?

Comment: Yes exactly, i edited it now, i can understand the misconception.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is correct. The set $$S = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : A \, x \le b \}$$ is always convex, regardless of the sign of the entries of $A$.